# Find the volume of an enclosed surface in spherical coordinates where one variable is equal another

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have an enclosed surface in spherical coordinates, where 
the distance $\rho$ from the origin to an arbitrary point equal to the polar angle $\phi$:

$$\rho = \phi$$

I need to find the volume of this enclosed surface, where
$$
\begin{matrix}
\phi \in [0,\pi]\\
\theta \in [0,2\pi]
\end{matrix}
$$

Comment: For future reference, it is often good to provide some details of what you have attempted on the problem, where you got stuck, etc.

Comment: Yes, I will be able to compute the rest. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, the volume enclosed by this surface is $\iiint_\mathcal W 1 \, dV,$ where $\mathcal W$ is the region enclosed by the surface. Observe that $\mathcal W = \{(\rho, \phi, \theta) \,|\, 0 \leq \rho \leq \phi, \, 0 \leq \phi \leq \pi, \text{ and } 0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi \}.$ Further, the Jacobian of the spherical coordinates transformation is $\rho^2 \sin \phi.$ Ultimately, we conclude that $$\text{volume} = \iiint_\mathcal W 1 \, dV = \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^\pi \int_0^\phi \rho^2 \sin \phi \, d \rho \, d \phi \, d \theta = \frac {2 \pi} 3 \int_0^\pi \phi^3 \sin \phi \, d \phi.$$ Can you finish the computation from here? (Hint: this requires integration by parts.)